# How can I meet Code Talker on motherbase?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Sometimes, when I leave the motherbase via helicopter, I see Code Talker on top of some buildings.

How can I meet him after returning to motherbase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, I have gone through every corner of mother base and he was nowhere to be found except when leaving on the chopper.

I cannot give a definitive proof but this seems to confirm my feelings.
Check DarkBlackHeart answer on this thread (beware, possible spoilers) :
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72429036

He also indicates who can be found on mother base and where.